# BlackBerry: browse specific folder, with a picture view

Tags: blackberry, view, directory

I don't find how to start Filepicker in a specific folder, with a picture view :
When I say`fp.setView(VIEW_PICTURES);` and `fp.setPath("file:///SDCard/Blackberry/travail/");` the view is correct, but not the path. I always go in the picture path, but with the good view (pictures only).
If I only say `fp.setPath("file:///SDCard/Blackberry/travail/");`, the path is correct, but the view is default one, with icons and labels.
Is ther any simply other way ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try this:

```
fp.setView(VIEW_ALL); // instead of VIEW_PICTURES
fp.setFilter(".jpg"); // show files with ".jpg" extention only
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this below link:

http://208.74.204.192/t5/Java-Development/Display-photos-in-a-specific-folder-with-the-m%C3%A9dia-player/m-p/1319435#M174957

and see the alishaik786 message you can get the information.

If you have reputation more than 20 then you can meet us in stackOverFlow's chat Room name is:
"Life for Blackberry " and ask directly questions.